# Pulling Users Emails with PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, get-aduser

I have script that will search within an OU and display username, names, AD group and description.

```
$ou = 'distinguishedName of the OU'
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($member in Get-ADGroupMember $_) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $member.SamAccountName
            Name           = $member.Name
            GroupName      = $_.Name
            Description    = $_.Description
        }
    }
} | Export-csv C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\NameOfMyFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Going off research I believe I have to use **Get-ADUser** and **mail** attribute.

Something like:

```
($members in Get-ADUser $1)

Email      = $1.mail
```

I have tried to alter this code and failed miserably.

Please could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for just **user object membership**, instead of using [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps) you can use [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) querying for "*users which's `MemberOf` attribute is equal to the group's `DistinguishedName`*":

```bash
$ou = 'distinguishedName of the OU'
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {
    $params = @{
        LDAPFilter = '(memberof={0})' -f $_.DistinguishedName
        Properties = 'mail'
    }
    foreach($member in Get-ADUser @params) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SamAccountName = $member.SamAccountName
            Name           = $member.Name
            Mail           = $member.Mail
            GroupName      = $_.Name
            Description    = $_.Description
        }
    }
} | Export-csv C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\NameOfMyFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @S.Mahmood i'm glad it did! :)